# How to write Undelete Triggers

Tags: trigger

```
trigger AccountUndelete on Account (after undelete) {

    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    for(Account undeletedAccount : trigger.new){ 
        undeletedAccount.Name = ('Undeleted :' + undeletedAccount.Name);
        accList.add(undeletedAccount);
    } 
    update accList;
}
```

I have tried this code to undelete the record from Recycle Bin, but I'm getting error while doing this operation. How can we resolve this issue?

> AccountUndelete: execution of AfterUndelete caused by:
> System.FinalException: Record is read-only Trigger.AccountUndelete:
> line 5, column 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly query Account record to update it. The records are read-only.

Below is the modified trigger:

```
trigger AccountUndelete on Account (after undelete) {

    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    for(Account undeletedAccount : [SELECT ID, Name from Account where Id IN : trigger.new]){ 
        undeletedAccount.Name = ('Undeleted :' + undeletedAccount.Name);
        accList.add(undeletedAccount);
    } 
    update accList;
}
```